# Retrieve name of Google signed in user from Firebase Auth in Dialogflow

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication, dialogflow-es, google-signin, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I have created a React-Native chatbot. Currently, the flow is:

1. User logs into React-Native iOS app via Google sign in using Firebase Auth
2. User interacts with chatbot. Messages are sent via iOS app to Dialogflow
3. Dialogflow maps intent and selects appropriate response

Most intents (and thus, responses) are mapped to fulfilment using a NodeJS webhook. I would like parse the user's name and ID to Dialogflow, so that Dialogflow can parse it to my webhook. How may I go about doing this? Do I have to use the in line editor in Dialogflow? If yes, how?

Comment: Hi @Vanesa Stanley, There is no straightforward method available in Dialogflow ES to parse the credentials. You can refer this [StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64632705/what-is-the-best-way-to-pass-credentials-to-and-from-dialogflow) for your requirement. Let me know if that helps.